# Complexity between if-else, switch and regex

Tags: javascript, performance, optimization, complexity-theory

I'm going to optimize javascript code in which I seen old code is like below,

```
var emcont = $('#emcont').val();
numericMatch = emcont.match(/\d/g);
if (numericMatch == null) {
    isValid = false;
    $('#msg_emcont').html(getMessage('msg_emcont')).show();
} else if (emcont.length != 14) {
    isValid = false;
    $('#msg_emcont').html(getMessage('msg_emcont')).show();
} else if (numericMatch.length && numericMatch.length != 10) {
    isValid = false;
    $('#msg_emcont').html(getMessage('msg_emcont')).show();
} else {
    $('#msg_emcont').html('').hide();
}
```

I going to convert if-else conditions into switch conditions, but the problem in the above code is 2nd condition validation used `emcont` variable so I can't directly use `numericMatch` in `switch` statement. So I decided used `emcont` variable directly in the `switch` statement like the below code,

```
switch(emcont)
    {
        case emcont.match(/\d/g) == null:
            isValid = false;
            $('#msg_emcont').html(getMessage('msg_emcont')).show();
            break;
        case emcont.length != 14:
            isValid = false;
            $('#msg_emcont').html(getMessage('msg_emcont')).show();
            break;
         case emcont.match(/\d/g).length && emcont.match(/\d/g).length != 10:
            isValid = false;
            $('#msg_emcont').html(getMessage('msg_emcont')).show();
            break;
        default:
            $('#msg_emcont').html('').hide();
            break;
    }
```

In used regex in switch case validation, so i need to know which code better in performance wise.

Comment: You cannot use the switch statement like that. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/switch#description

Comment: and...[Which is faster](https://ericlippert.com/2012/12/17/performance-rant/)

Comment: Why do people think code is better moving to a switch? Want to make your code better? STOP looking up the element in the DOM over and over again.

Comment: Your switch should be `switch(true)`, but this is just bad practice using it this way.

Comment: You could just make a single regular expression that tests that. There really does not need to be 3 checks. What is the pattern you expect? something like XXX-1234567890???

Comment: Maybe I should've said, you _should not_ use the switch like that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please do not abuse side effects of `switch(true)` which is what you meant

This is DRY and easier to read

```js
var emcont = $('#emcont').val();
const numericMatch = emcont.match(/\d/g);
$('#msg_emcont')
  .html(getMessage('msg_emcont'))
  .toggle(
    numericMatch == null || 
    emcont.length != 14  || 
    (numericMatch.length && numericMatch.length != 10)
  )
```

You might even consider to move

```
$('#msg_emcont').html(getMessage('msg_emcont'))
```

to the page load so it is only done once

Comment: @ShriSamarth don't take downvotes personally. Using a switch to test boolean statements is a huge antipattern and that is what is voted down, not you

Comment: Actually, I optimized the jquery code containing so many if-else conditions as I mentioned in my question. That code is used for tablet webview. The process is user condition contains 5 big complex forms. What is the way I can optimize that code? My client told me the code took a lot of time to execute.

Comment: Make sure to a) delegate close to the same elements (like event listeners on a container) b) cache the elements if you need to reuse. I would have to see the code in question

Comment: And html5 form validation probably can get rid of must of the javascript code. As I said in the comment, all those length checks could be done in one reg exp check if there is a known pattern. So the code could be even smaller.